# ZF2 SessionManager usage

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am new to ZF2 and not quite used to how to do stuff. I want to use session to keep track of an user (remember me). I had this code in one part of my class:

```
$sessionManager = new \Zend\Session\SessionManager();
$sessionManager->rememberMe($time);

// i want to keep track of my user id too
$populateStorage = array('user_id' => $user->getId());
$storage = new ArrayStorage($populateStorage);
$sessionManager->setStorage($storage);
```

Ok, so far so good. When i try:

```
var_dump($sessionManager->getStorage());
```

I get the expected data.

In another part of my program, i want to retreive my data again (a  bit like containers):

```
$sessionManager = new \Zend\Session\SessionManager();
var_dump($sessionManager->getStorage());
```

This only returns an empty object.
I guess this is due to the "new" and i think i have to implement SessionManager in a different way, but how? I do not know. This is what i came up with:

In my Module i now have:

```
public function onBootstrap(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $e)
{
    $config = $e->getApplication()
            ->getServiceManager()
            ->get('Configuration');

    $sessionConfig = new SessionConfig();
    $sessionConfig->setOptions($config['session']);
    $sessionManager = new SessionManager($sessionConfig);
    $sessionManager->start();
```

In my module.config:

```
'session' => array(
    'remember_me_seconds' => 2419200,
    'use_cookies' => true,
    'cookie_httponly' => true,
),
```

But how to procede? How do i get the instance for my sessionManager?

Answer (score 15):

There is not well documented SessionManagerFactory ([zf2 api doc](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.2/classes/Zend.Session.Service.SessionManagerFactory.html)) and SessionConfigFactory ([zf2 api doc](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.2/classes/Zend.Session.Service.SessionConfigFactory.html)). With those is instantiate SessionManager very easy, just put these factories to your ServiceManager configuration:

```
'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        'Zend\Session\SessionManager' => 'Zend\Session\Service\SessionManagerFactory',
        'Zend\Session\Config\ConfigInterface' => 'Zend\Session\Service\SessionConfigFactory',
    ],
],
```

and to module configuration put your session options, under the session_config key:

```
'session_config' => [
    'remember_me_seconds' => 2419200,
    'use_cookies' => true,
    'cookie_httponly' => true,
],
```

and that's it, now you can grab SessionManager from service locator anywhere, for example in controller:

```
/** @var Zend\Session\SessionManager $sm */
$sessionManager = $this->serviceLocator->get('Zend\Session\SessionManager');
```

This is available as of 2.2 version of Zend Framework ([related pull request](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/pull/4268)).

Comment: Great, didn't noticed this very useful service!

Comment: It's very unfortunate that Zend 2 does not have any proper documentation. It seems that the zend 2 is for the people who develops it only.

Comment: Where does the second code go? The `session_config`

Answer (score 2):

In my project i use example from other source (book or official documentation, forget).

Main `Module.php` file:

```
namespace Application;

class Module
{
    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'Zend\Session\SessionManager' => function ($sm){
                    $config = $sm->get('config');
                    if (isset($config['session'])){
                        $session_config = $config['session'];

                        $sessionConfig = null;
                        if (isset($session_config['config'])){
                            $class = isset($session_config['config']['class'])
                                ? $session_config['config']['class']
                                : 'Zend\Session\Config\SessionConfig';
                            $options = isset($session_config['config']['options'])
                                ? $session_config['config']['options']
                                : array();
                            $sessionConfig = new $class();
                            $sessionConfig->setOptions($options);
                        }

                        $sessionStorage = null;
                        if (isset($session_config['storage'])){
                            $class = $session_config['storage'];
                            $sessionStorage = new $class();
                        }

                        $sessionSaveHandler = null;
                        if (isset($session_config['save_handler'])){
                            // class should be fetched from service manager
                            // since it will require constructor arguments
                            $sessionSaveHandler = $sm->get($session_config['save_handler']);
                        }

                        $sessionManager = new SessionManager(
                            $sessionConfig,
                            $sessionStorage,
                            $sessionSaveHandler
                        );

                        if (isset($session_config['validator'])){
                            $chain = $sessionManager->getValidatorChain();
                            foreach ($session_config['validator'] as $validator){
                                $validator = new $validator();
                                $chain->attach('session.validate', array(
                                    $validator,
                                    'isValid'
                                ));
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        $sessionManager = new SessionManager();
                    }
                    Container::setDefaultManager($sessionManager);
                    return $sessionManager;
                },
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

My `config/autoload/global.php` config file:

```
return array(
    'session' => array(
        'config' => array(
            'class' => 'Zend\Session\Config\SessionConfig',
            'options' => array(
                'use_cookies' => true,
            ),
        ),
        'storage' => 'Zend\Session\Storage\SessionArrayStorage',
        'validators' => array(
            array(
                'Zend\Session\Validator\RemoteAddr',
                'Zend\Session\Validator\HttpUserAgent',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

To get `user_id` from session:

```
$sessionStorage = $sm->get('Zend\Session\SessionManager')
    ->getStorage();
$user_id = $sessionStorage->user_id;
```