# Cookie value does not changed

Tags: php, cookies, zend-framework2, session-cookies

I am working in Zend framework 2 in that I have set the cookie configuration on module.php file which is:

```
$sessionConfig = new \Zend\Session\Config\SessionConfig();
$sessionConfig->setHashFunction("sha512")->setHashBitsPerCharacter(6)->setGcMaxlifetime(3600)->setCookieHttpOnly(true)->setRememberMeSeconds(3600);
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on"){
     $sessionConfig->setCookieSecure(true);
}
```

When I logged in or logged out my cookie value is remain same, so how to change the cookie value which is stored in "PHPSESSID".

Comment: can you change the cookie in your logout function?

Comment: It is not a best practice to change the value of PHPSESSID manually ?, may be there are some functions in zf2 but I can not able to find those functions.

Comment: You can use Zend\Session\SessionManager `s regenerateId() for the session manager you are using for the auth process.

Comment: @JannesBotis how to use this becase I am not using this sessionManager, but this function session_regenerate_id() is working for me

Comment: Internally, regenerateId() will call built-in session_regenerate_id(), but do you use Zend\Authentication for your auth? If so, I would suggest get the SessionManager used by it(probably the dafault one) and call regenerateId(). Thus doing it the standard zend way.

Comment: I am using "Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService" from that It does not providing SessionManager

Comment: AuthenticationService constructor `s 1st argument is "Storage\StorageInterface $storage = null". If not provided, then getStorage() uses "Storage\Session()", which will use the default session manager. You cannot get the session manager through AuthenticationService. You can try something like $this->serviceLocator->get('Zend\Session\SessionManager')->regenerateId(); in zf2(will not work in zf3)

Comment: @JannesBotis it gives the error "Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Zend\Session\SessionManager"

Comment: You need to provide the factory for SessionManager. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20643393

Comment: @JannesBotis thanks